# I have warnings when casting Java classes

Tags: java, classcastexception

### I parse OpenApi structure:

[image]

### My Solution

I am walking recursively through the object tree. When I find Schema class I call another function

```
private void parseSchemas(Object object) {
    if (object == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (object.getClass() == OpenAPI.class && ((OpenAPI) object).getPaths() != null) {
        ((OpenAPI) object).getPaths().values().forEach(this::parseSchemas);
    } else if (object.getClass() == PathItem.class) {
        parseSchemas(((PathItem) object).getGet());
        parseSchemas(((PathItem) object).getPost());
        parseSchemas(((PathItem) object).getDelete());
        parseSchemas(((PathItem) object).getPut());
        parseSchemas(((PathItem) object).getHead());
    }
    if (object.getClass() == Operation.class && ((Operation) object).getResponses() != null) {
        ((Operation) object).getResponses().values().forEach(this::parseSchemas);
    }
    if (object.getClass() == Operation.class && ((Operation) object).getParameters() != null) {
        ((Operation) object).getParameters().forEach(o -> parseSchemas(o.getSchema()));
    }
    if (object.getClass() == ApiResponse.class && ((ApiResponse) object).getContent() != null) {
        parseSchemas(((ApiResponse) object).getContent());
    }
    if (object.getClass() == Content.class) {
        ((Content) object).values().forEach(this::parseSchemas);
    }
    if (object.getClass() == MediaType.class && ((MediaType) object).getSchema() != null) {
        parseSchemas(((MediaType) object).getSchema());
    }
    if (object.getClass() == (StringSchema.class)) {
        defineSchemaAndValues((StringSchema) object);
    }
    if ((object.getClass().getSuperclass() == Schema.class || object.getClass() == Schema.class)
            && ((Schema) object).getProperties() != null) {
        ((Schema) object).getProperties().values().forEach(this::parseSchemas);
    }
    if ((object.getClass().getSuperclass() == Schema.class || object.getClass() == Schema.class)) {
        defineSchemaAndValues((Schema) object);
    }
}
```

### Problem

I have warnings when casting Schema class. Schema - Generic class.

[image]

Comment: Just a general note: instead of checking the equality between classes and optionally a superclass which fails for super-super-classes, use [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)